# WebDriver with php

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to loop over all elements of a certain class with Webdriver and  then delve into each iterations result in php.

So far i have the following.

```
$elements = self::$driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath("//*[@class='foo']"));

foreach( $elements as $elem ) {

    // use elem to burrow in to given "this" element

}
```

I can successfully loop over all elements but cannot use $elem to any avail.  I can getTagName() etc but i want to be able to find elements within "this" $elem

For better understanding... In jQuery it would be something like

```
$('.foo').each( function() {
     $bar = $(this).find('.bar');
     // query bar
})
```

Essentially i need to check what type of input is inside and then either click it, select, type something etc... and move to the next.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am ready to rip parts off my body.

Comment: You could also use  `$(".foo .bar").each` in jQuery instead. You could do the same using xpath.

Comment: I will give that a blast, i guess i could delve down in each query and loop over like results.  Thanks

Comment: Also, in Java you could do something akin to `element.findElements` maybe that would also work here.

Comment: @apokryfos I tried elem->findElements(...) but it was not having any of it.

Comment: @apokryfos RE: $(".foo .bar) example: i guess i wanted to be sure i had all the elements and can throw an exception / react if all cases are not found within each element.  The api that produces the form i am testing is not in my direct control, some cases will not be present on any given test - but the elements always will be.  Thanks for your suggestions.